# Selling equipment on this site

Tags: discussion

I want to sell my Rebel Xt and buy a 5D. Is it acceptable to post ads for sale.
This is a one time thing for me.

Comment: Why is the question being downvoted? We can answer no, but it's a perfectly legitimate question. IMO the downvotes are not called for.

Comment: @Reid I guess someone didn't agree with the idea. It had been suggested as a related site once we're out of beta over in this question: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/304/additional-sidelines-to-the-site (as you mention in your answer. oops)

Comment: I'm sure that's what happened. But aren't votes on a question supposed to reflect the legitimacy of its being asked and not as a shorthand answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome!

The short answer is no.

There has, however, been some interest in an affiliated marketplace, so something like that may arise in the future. Do a search here on meta for the current status and please do participate in the process if you're interested.

Comment: Agreed, does not contribute to the body of photographic knowledge